# Finding the common distribution

Tags: probability

In a box there are four toys: $3$ balls and one bear. the baby pick $2$ toys from the box with no return.

Let:

$B-$ the number of balls that the baby took.

$N-$ the number of toys till the first ball.

Find the common distribution of $B$ and $I$

*Attempt:*

$N\sim G(3/4)$

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
  B\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large N}{\phantom{l}} 
    & 0 & 1 & 2 &\\ 
 \hline
  0 & 0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{red}0& \\ 
 \hline
  1 & 0 & \color{pink}{3/4} & ?& \\ 
 \hline
  2 & 0 & ? & ?& \\ 
 \hline
   &  &  & & \Sigma=1\\ 
 \hline
\end{array}$

Pr$(N=1,B=0)=\color{blue}0$

Pr$(N=2,B=0)=\color{red}0$

Pr$(N=1,B=1)=\color{pink}{\frac{3}{4}}$

I'm not sure how to fill in the table, sorry about my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top row of your matrix is correct, since it is of course impossible for the baby to pick $0$ balls.

$P(B=1,N=0)$ is not $0$, however: the baby can pick a ball for the first toy, and then the bear, so then $B=1$ and $N=0$. The probability of this is $\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{4}$

You also miscalculated $P(B=1,N=1)$.  For this to happen, the baby first picks the bead, and then a ball, and the chance of that is $\frac{1}{4}$

And finally, it is not true that $P(B=2,N=0)$ is not $0$.  This is the babby picking two balls, which has a probability of $\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{2}$

Given that there is only $1$ toy that is not a ball, $N$ can only be $0$ or $1$. Hence, $P(B=1,N=2)=P(b=2,N=2)=0$

And finally, $P(B=2,N=1)=0$ since that would mean the baby would pick a bear and then two balls.

So, the resulting matrix is:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
  B\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large N}{\phantom{l}} 
    & 0 & 1 & 2 &\\ 
 \hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \\ 
 \hline
  1 & 1/4 & 1/4 & 0& \\ 
 \hline
  2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0& \\ 
 \hline
   &  &  & & \Sigma=1\\ 
 \hline
\end{array}$